# Having trouble installing Grunt through the command line

Tags: json, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to install the Grunt command line and am having difficulty installing it. I have followed Chris Coyier's walkthrough very closely and do not see where I am going wrong. My project name is 'ryan' and here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ryan",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2"
  }
}
```

Grunt seemed to install fine as node_modules was installed into the project folder. However, once I enter 'npm install -g grunt-cli' it seems to fail. any solutions:

My terminal:

```
ryans-mbp:ryan rynslmns$ npm install -g grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-    writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.2
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/rynslmns/Desktop/ryan
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/rynslmns/Desktop/ryan/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: what about running `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli` instead ?

Answer (score 2):

It is because the user you're using doesn't have permissions to write to the install folder where node.js is installed.

To install you would need to run with: `sudo npm install grunt-cli -g`

But I highly recommend running node/npm without requiring sudo. There are many ways, here is a way to install node.js without needing sudo access:

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
mkdir ~/local
mkdir ~/node-latest-install
cd ~/node-latest-install
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
./configure --prefix=~/local
make install
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Visit https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814 for more ways to do it (and where I copied this way from).